# Using Visual Studio 2005 with ClearCase Eclipsed Files

Tags: visual-studio, clearcase

I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2005 with ClearCase eclipsed files (view private which "eclipse" a versioned file), but any time I save the file in VS, it becomes uneclipsed, and returns to the versioned file. In Linux, I use VIM instead of Visual Studio, and get around this problem by setting backupcopy=yes, thereby forcing it to save files by writing to a new file and then copying the new file over the existing one, instead of moving the original file out of the way (which undoes the eclipse) and then writing a new file, but in Windows, I'd like to use Visual Studio (since the tree also includes C# code compiled under VS). Is there any way to teach it to save files this way?

Comment: If you do not have any better answer, I will get those points back for you (albeit "slowly"): 1/ you should not have to spend them in the first place, 2/ what about your next tricky question, if your rep drop so much you can not allow to set a "large" incentive on it ?

Comment: As documented in this uservoice entry ( http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/117165-fix-the-bounty-system ), bounty sucks on so many level...

Comment: since you didn't like the bounty, I didn't mark it as accepted; I would do so now, but for some reason, I don't see the check mark! Do questions expire after a certain point?

Comment: @Mikeage: yes, that's the all point of bounty: they expire after 7 days ;-). See this blog entry (and check out the comments): http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions : look for my remarks in those comments.

Comment: i understand the bounty logic; but if it expired, why can't I mark your response as accepted?

Comment: @Mikeage: you mean, there is no more "tick" clickable right now ? Even though that "tick" would only get 15 points rep (since the bounty is expired), that would look like a bug to me. If you confirm, I will make a uservoice case reporting this.

Comment: Hi there. BUG registered in uservoice: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/121182-bug-no-more-answer-tick-mark-after-an-unresolved-bounty . 
Leave a comment on it if you think it is incorrect or needs to be completed.

Comment: Hi again Mikeage. Since http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/121182-bug-no-more-answer-tick-mark-after-an-unresolved-bounty is reportedly completed, I would like to know if you do see those "ticks" back. Could you let me know (with a comment on my answer) ?

Comment: no. perhaps it's related to the fact that I upvoted your answer? [I can't change that now, since the vote is too old]

Comment: @Mikeage For your information, the non-selection of an official answer is by design for now: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/why-cant-an-answer-can-be-accepted-after-an-unresolved-bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is still reading this... I just discovered that Visual Studio 2008 appears to work just fine. Go figure...

Answer (score 2):

I do not think Visual Studio does save file in a particular way that may cause the file to be first removed, then written.

Considering that, with developer's environment as Windows with Visual Studio, eclipsed
files often happen just by writing a file case sensitive and later not case sensitive.
Hence, did you check the case of your file ?

Could you also check the config spec associated with your Windows view ? (and compare it to your Linux view).

---

I just spend 1/2h with a Visual Studio 2005 / ClearCase / dynamic view and... I do see the same thing!

The only workaround I can fathom is to add a non-selection rule:

```
element /my/private/file -none
```

That way, even though VS2005 remove then add the private file when saving it, ClearCase does not try to restore the versionned file, since it is not selected at all.

Si, the answer may not reside within VS2005 (I studied the options without seeing any obvious setting altering the saving process...), but rather within ClearCase.

Let me know if it helps.

---

As noted in the comment, the downside of this approach is "un-eclipse" can no longer be a matter of moving/removing the private file to let ClearCase dynamically restore the versionned file.

Now, that step must be complemented with another one, which is to comment  the non-selection rule in the config spec.

Comment: The eclipsing is on purpose. In vim (both win+linux), I can control the style of saves and see this behavior. Another editor that behaves like MSVC, Multi-Edit, shows it even clearer, as the temporary file is left in the directory.

The configspecs are identical, and the files are all lowercase only

Comment: I understand eclipsing is on purpose (like on purpose hijacked files in a snapshot view). I did not realize Visual Studio had that kind of process when saving a file. I will ask the developers I am in contact with for more information tomorrow.

Comment: Interesting idea; I'll setting my eclipse script to add this automatically.

OTOH, it was nice to be able to un-eclipse files just by deleting them.