# Disabling / Suppressing SD(HC) Write Protect

Tags: driver, sdhc

I know that the write protect tab in SD cards is not a real hardware protection, but a simple signal to the reader that the card is write protected. For example, the CHDK project for Canon cameras specifically ignores it, and once had a cheap flash reader ($2 by mail from Hong Kong) which didn't recognize it.

Is there any way (registry hack, custom driver, anything) on Windows to prevent this flag from being set? I'd like my SDHC reader to also ignore the write protect tab; has anyone ever heard / seen such a thing before?

Comment: +1 for giving it an higher visibility on "unanswered" tab. See comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487737. 3 down, 12 to go (1 per day) Note: could you confirm the bug I mention in the comments of question 487737 ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about any registry but the controller *MUST* support such feature (or lack of feature ^_^)
from a driver point of view, I doubt this is standardized.

Good luck